# Entity Framework Core database migration via Azure Function startup

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-functions

I am trying to run `DbContext.Database.migrate()` from an Azure Function app startup class. But I get an error. I am aware of this caveat [DI in .net azure functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection):

> The startup class is meant for only setup and registration. Avoid using services registered at startup during the startup process. For instance, don't try to log a message in a logger that is being registered during startup. This point of the registration process is too early for your services to be available for use. After the Configure method is run, the Functions runtime continues to register additional dependencies, which can affect how your services operate.

This is the error I get :

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.IFileLoggingStatusManager' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Diagnostics.HostFileLoggerProvider'.

We can find a similar issue here: [EF Core Migrations in Azure Function startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017552/ef-core-migrations-in-azure-function-startup)

Code:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();

    using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();

    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<VOTSContext>();

    context.Database.Migrate();
}
```

This is how it can be run from ASP.NET Core:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        db.Database.Migrate();
    }

    host.Run();
}
```