# Errror in FunctionStartup with Azure Functions .NET 6.0 EFCore Dependyinjection, IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-functions, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.IFileLoggingStatusManager' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Diagnostics.HostFileLoggerProvider'.

DBContext.cs:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, Guid, IdentityUserClaim<Guid>, UserRole, IdentityUserLogin<Guid>, IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>, IdentityUserToken<Guid>>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }
}
```

Dependencies:

```
<PackageReference Include="Flurl" Version="3.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.19.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.15.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.19.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.10.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Common" Version="12.9.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Files.Shares" Version="12.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.8.0" />
<PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="10.3.4" />
<PackageReference Include="HtmlSanitizer" Version="6.0.453" />
<PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="9.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="9.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Azure" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="5.2.9" />
<PackageReference Include="NetTopologySuite" Version="2.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="7.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="ProjNet" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.0">
```

Startup.cs:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace Technoleon.Api
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public Startup() { }

        IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        private static readonly RetryPolicy _retryPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>().WaitAndRetry(5, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

        public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigurationBuilder
                   .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(builder.GetContext().ApplicationRootPath, "appsettings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: true).Build();
        }

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            Configuration = builder.GetContext().Configuration;
            ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

            var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();

            using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
            {
                var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                _retryPolicy.Execute(() => context.Database.EnsureCreated());
                _retryPolicy.Execute(() => context.Database.Migrate());

                var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<UserManager<User>>();
                _retryPolicy.Execute(() => UserData.Seed(userManager));
            }
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton(this);

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(options, Configuration.GetConnectionString("Technoleon"),
                sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), null)
                .UseNetTopologySuite()
                .UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery)
            ));

            services.AddLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder.AddApplicationInsights();
                builder.AddFilter<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("", LogLevel.Trace);
            });

            #ConfigureOtherServices...
        }
    }
}
```

I have rebuilt my web app from .NET 5 to Azure Functions .NET 6.

I got an Azure Functions project in .NET 6.0 with EF Core and dependency injection. I am configuring my project in `Startup.cs` with `FunctionsStartup`.

When trying to configure my local SQL Server database, I get this error:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.IFileLoggingStatusManager' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Diagnostics.HostFileLoggerProvider'.*

It crashes when I try to call:

```
var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

How can I solve this error?

Please let me know if you need some additional information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The services are not in a full 'workable' state while you are still inside the `Configure` method. Read the 'Caveats' here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

One workaround is to register a custom `IWebJobStartup` class in your function app, which gets called after successful initialization of the services. It's a safe place to get back the db context from services. This answer has a sample: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68207734/687190

Another workaround is to apply your migrations in your pipeline, before you deploy your app (if you are using CI/CD). Here's a link how to do it with an older version, but the concept is the same. https://dibranmulder.github.io/2018/08/23/Azure-functions-V2-with-EF-Core/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `IFileLoggingStatusManager` which is necessary for `HostFileLoggerProvider` is not set up yet at the time you are creating the dependency injection container and attempt to resolve the logger in the StartUp class.

You would be able to solve the problem delay logging until the application has fully started.

If you check this [startup code of WebJobs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Script/ScriptHostBuilderExtensions.cs), you will find that first we add logger, then the external external startup is executed and finally the required logging services are added. Make sure you are following this order.

For more information read this [Dependency injection in ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0#service-lifetimes) and also check this [discussion](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6783) in GitHub.