# EF Core DbContext in Azure Functions with Repository

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, azure-functions, ef-core-6.0

I've an Azure Function App with multiple Azure functions and EF Core 6.

In the **Startup.cs** I add the repository with `AddScoped` and pass the `connectionString`.

```
class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString");
        builder.Services.AddScoped<SQLRepository>(x => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<SQLRepository>(x, connectionString));
    }
}
```

The repository itself create the `dbContext` and initiate the migration.

```
public class SQLRepository
{
    private readonly MyDBContext _context;

    public SQLRepository(String connectionString)
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDBContext>().UseSqlServer(connectionString).Options;            
        _context = new MyDBContext(options);
        _context.Database.Migrate();
    }
}
```

But since the `Configure` in `Startup` is called twice (once for each Azure function) the second time the repository is created, I get the error, the object `__EFMigrationsHistory` exists. Maybe, because the first migration is still in progress as the second try is started.

Is there a way to prevent this? Or do I have to perform the migration in an extra Azure function that is only called on start once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [EF Core Migrations in Azure Function startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017552/ef-core-migrations-in-azure-function-startup) I use a custom `IWebJobsStartup` and perform the migration there and not in the `SQLRepository` itself.