# How to run EF Core database migrations from an Azure Function startup like we do in .NET 6 API startup

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions, ef-core-6.0

I have a .NET 6 Azure Function app project and clean architecture like setup. I have a EF Core 6 setup in persistence layer where database migrations reside. I understand we need design-time migrations as well.

Only one piece I am missing: how could I run database migrations automatically on function start up like in an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project? Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: This answer should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64806909/1756249

Comment: This doesn't answer how to run the migrations at function startup however? though I am thinking whether its a good practise to run db migrations on function startup in consumption plan as there is  situation of cold start already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to run EF Core database migrations from an Azure Function startup.

Install the below NuGet packages.

```cs
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

- We can use the same  `Migrate()`  as we do in the`.NET 6 API startup`.

> whether its a good practice to run db migrations on function startup in consumption plan as there is situation of cold start already.

- Even though it is possible to run DB migrations from functions startup (Consumption plan), it is not the recommended way to do.
- It will increase the cold start time of the function which you are already facing.
- To avoid this run the migrations outside the Startup.
- This ensures that it is executed only when necessary, which helps in improving the performance of the Function.

To run EF Core database migrations automatically on function startup, we can use the  `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`  interface to create a new instance of  `DbContext`  at design time.

This interface is used by  `EF Core tools`  to create a new instance of  `DbContext`  when running commands like  `dotnet ef migrations add`  or  `dotnet ef database update`.

To use this interface, you need to create a new class that implements  `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`  and returns a new instance of your  `DbContext`.

Refer  [Entity Framework with Azure Functions](https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/using-entity-framework-with-azure-functions-a32d09382b94)  for more details.